# Convert mysql query result (object array) to json

Tags: python

i want to convert from mysql query result.

```
DealerID | Dealer Name | SubDealerID | Subdealer Name
AL06        A L A S K A      0001       A L A S K A JKT
AL06        A L A S K A      AG01       AGUS SANTOSO,BPK.
AL06        A L A S K A      IM01       IMPERIAL, TOKO
AL09      ALFA ELECTRONIC    0001       ALFA ELECTRONIC
AL09      ALFA ELECTRONIC    AN01       ANGGA MUHAMAD SOLEH
AL09      ALFA ELECTRONIC    ER01       ERWIN KURNIAWAN
AL10         PT.ALFA         0001       PT.ALFA RETAILINDO       TBK
AL10         PT.ALFA         AL01       PT. ALFA RETAILINDO TBK
AL10         PT.ALFA         AL02       PT.ALFA RETAILINDO TBK     DPK
AL10         PT.ALFA         AL03       PT.ALFA RETAILINDO TBK     STR
AL10         PT.ALFA         AL04       PT.ALFA RETAILINDO TBK
AL10         PT.ALFA         AL05       PT.ALFA RETAILINDO  TBK    KBY
```

i need convert to this json format using python flask :

```
{
        "data":
        {
                "dealerID": "AL06",
                "dealer": "A L A S K A",
                "sdealer" : [
                        { "sdi": "AG01","sdealer": "AGUS SANTOSO,BPK."},
                        { "sdi": "IM01","sdealer": "IMPERIAL, TOKO"}
                        ]
         }
    }
```

can someone help me, thanks

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: thank bruno, if you dont have idea, just stay calm and cool

Comment: @yk-toe what you ask for is totally trivial and is a 10mn job at most, now you post here basically asking someone to do it for you for free, not showing the least effort.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i did a bad job.But i have try my best,this is my idea:

```
jsons   = {"data":[]}
det     = {} # use to check if have same id
#query() return cursor.fetchall()
for p in query("select * from temp"):
    if p[0] in list(det.keys()):
        jsons["data"][ det[ p[0] ] ]["sdealer"].append({ "sdi": p[2],"sdealer": p[3]})
    else:
        form      = { "dealerID":p[0],
                  "dealer":p[1],
                  "sdealer":[
                    { "sdi": p[2],"sdealer": p[3]}
                    ]}
        det[p[0]] = 0 if det == {} else list(det.values())[-1] + 1
        jsons["data"].append(form)
print(jsons)
```